# Where can I find information about previous Kerbals?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

So I've recently started playing Kerbal Space Program, with disastrous results: the survival rate of any Kerbal entering any of my ships is currently 1 survival for every 30 deaths. My question is, is there a place where the names and possible cause of deaths (or achievements) of my Kerbals is stored? I think it would be awesome to have a list of heroes (read: tragic guinea pigs). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there is currently no way to see that information.  It's been suggested as an additional feature, but currently, there's no record of your past Kerbals.  They are randomly generated each and every time.

Comment: Well everyone except Bill, Jeb, and Bob.